# xcodebuild default build path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to make a FAT framework following [this guide](https://theswiftdev.com/2018/01/25/deep-dive-into-swift-frameworks/)

What I'd like to understand is the xcodebuild build path. Based on that tutorial, this is created at the beginning:

```
BUILD_PATH="${SRCROOT}/build"
```

Now when I make a build, the builds for Release-iphoneos and Release-iphonesimulator go into that `build` folder. Is this a predefined variable that can be set to tell Xcode where your builds can go? Because based on [this other tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2658-creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial): `BUILD_DIR` gets passed to xcodebuild.

I was wondering what the difference is here and how Xcode handles these arguments.

How does setting this directory work with `DerivedData`?

Also on the topics of building, does Xcode cache builds? Sometimes after I build and do a `ls -al` on my frameworks, they don't have current timestamps. But once I delete the build directory, it seems to force Xcode to build again and then I get "fresh" frameworks created. Is Xcode caching the build and not replacing the build? Is there a way to force it?